# Returning html ID via path of Views of MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-core, validation, model-view-controller, formwizard, server-side-validation

I am using **wizard in my page** and **server side validation** using razor view.
[output page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeXCn.png)
[Index.cshtml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRH7U.png)

For validation in #step-3/#step-2 wizard i want my page goes to id->step-3 but it goes to #step-1 or at the start of wizard page

I have to return the id of html page in returning views of controller.[controller.cshtml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7RiA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `Tempdata and js`,here is a demo:

action:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(Contact contData)
        {
            TempData["id"] = "step-3";
            return View();
        }
```

View:

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="step-1" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Step 1</h3>
        <p>Some content in step 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="step-2" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Step 2</h3>
        <p>Some content in step 2.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="step-3" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Step 3</h3>
        <p>Some content in step 3.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<form method="post">
    <button>submit</button>
</form>
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var s = "@TempData["id"]";
            var indexValue=0;
            $(".tab-pane").each(function (index) {
                if ($(this).attr("id") == s) {
                    $(this).addClass("in active");
                    indexValue=index;
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass("in active");
                }
            })
            $(".myClass").each(function (index) {
                if (indexValue==index) {
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                    indexValue=index;
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass("active");
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
    
}
```

result:

[image]